# Why can only one person talk at a time over internet voice chat?

Tags: networking, firewall, skype, voip, voice-chat

It seems like this is a somewhat localized problem. When using any of a variety of chat applications: whereby, Skype, teamviewer, zoom - it seems as though only one individual can transmit data at a time.

If I am talking, the other person cannot interject. And vice versa.

This leads me to believe that these connections are using UDP data since they are not guaranteeing deliverability.

I am not sure if this is a firewall issue, a networking configuration issue, or a local network configuration issue on client computers. This happens to two computers in my network that I have identified. Both are running windows 10.

It’s frustrating when we cannot rudely interject someone’s speech to tell them something! All jokes aside, it would be nice to be able to have bidirectional traffic, because it seems that we do not.

We are also using google WiFi. I have a few netgear managed switches in my network also.

What should I be looking for?

Comment: I've never observed this issue. Mostly, volume means I cannot whar someone else over my own talking.

Comment: Well it is rather rude to interrupt people who are talking under many circumstances ... working in a call centre we are not allowed to do this ...

Comment: I'd suspect my audio subsystems before I'd suspect networking. If you're using your laptop's built-in speakers and mic, you've got a speakerphone that needs to keep the speaker output from being picked up by the mic and causing echo or feedback. Often this can mean cutting back the mic gain while moderate to loud sound is coming out of the speakers. Edit your question to include details of your audio hardware situation and what you've tried w.r.t. switching out headsets or using a different PC/laptop/tablet/smartphone.

Comment: I agree completely agree that it is rude to interrupt. No debate there. However, in the event that you -need- to cut someone off; such as in telehealth sessions where someone wants to add something to an incorrectly received response, we have noticed that if someone is currently talking - they are not able to hear US speak until they stop what they are saying. Once they have stopped talking, they can hear us fine. I am befuddled.

Comment: Also - for the record, I have tested this one two different machines. One is in my studio, where the audio I/O goes through a mixing board and then an audio AD/DA interface to the PC. The other machine has an external USB Condenser microphone attached. These are both on the same network.